# How to wait until I receive a certain status in Perl coding?

Tags: regex, perl

In my Perl program I am expecting a certain value, say "abc", inside a variable. I have to wait until I receive the status as abc.

For example:

```
my $status = `cmviewcl -p $pkg_name | awk 'END {print \$2}'`;
```

I am getting status say "pqrst". I have to wait until it is changed to "abc". How to do that in Perl coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put it into a while loop:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $status = '';
while ( $status ne 'abc' ) {
    $status = `cmviewcl -p $pkg_name | awk 'END {print \$2}'`;
    sleep(1);   #sleep for however long is appropriate for you
}

... #Rest of code
```

Comment: You probably don't want to sleep after getting the correct status, so you probably need to adjust the loop a bit.  It partly depends on whether the following code uses the value of `$status`…though since it must be `abc` when the loop finishes, there's hardly any need to do so.

Comment: why not `while ( \`CODE\` ne 'abc') { sleep(1);}` ? You avoid the sleep after the status is reached.

Comment: That's a fair point.  Assuming you don't need the value of `$status` later on, you could use @Paulchenkiller solution, and assuming you do need it, you could move the `sleep` up one line.  Of course you could remove the `sleep` altogether as long as you know that the command isn't too system intensive.

Comment: Well. You know the return value of the code. you check against it :P

Comment: <facepalm> - that settles it... bedtime for me.